# Apache High CPU Usage, self calls in server-status

Tags: apache

So I am trying to figure our why Apache while normally idles at 25% of CPU and 20% of RAM sometimes spikes to 100~300% alloted CPU and 100% of alloted RAM.

When I go to http://ip.ip.ip.ip/server-status I can see normal calls for pages but then there are about 120 lines like this.

```
Srv PID Acc M   CPU     SS  Req Conn    Child   Slot    Client  VHost   Request
87-0    -   0/0/214 .   0.28    1293    0   0.0 0.00    15.57   ::1 ds1234.dedicated.turbodns.co.uk OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

While the ds1234.dedicated.turbodns.co.uk is the public domain for the server.
They have no outsider IP so there is nothing I can ban.

Are these lines something to be worried about? Since there can be between 80 and 120 at any time and they don't appear in this area

```
_____W___._.__W__._._K__W_.___._._...._KW_W_CW_________R_..R__..
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, added the question

Comment: It's worth noting that the request listed in `server-status` only lists the last request that the child handled, even if that child is not doing anything anymore. In the line you highlighted, that thread isn't doing anything, as `.` means "Open slot with no current process"

Comment: So no need to worry?
Then how can i track where is the usage coming cause if I use top, it just says httpd but not the specific file causing the server usage.

Comment: You have to use a variety of tools. server-status can tell you the memory, cpu etc. of each child, but you will likely have to catch it in the act. the server logs may help by saying which paths cause errors or have the most bytes transferred etc.